# linear transformation and group theory

Tags: linear-transformations

Find the image of the circle x^2+y^2=9 under the transformation : $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 4\\3 & 6\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix}$=L$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix}$=$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 4\\3 & 6\end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$=(1/12-12)$\begin{bmatrix}6 & -4\\-3 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix}$

but 1/0 is invalid... :)

Comment: The linear map has determinant 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** the image must lie within the span of the vector $\pmatrix{2\\3}$

Comment: does that mean that it will be x=x' and y=y' ?

Comment: which => x^2 + y^2 = 9 (didn't change)

Comment: No. That means that for every $(x',y'),$ $y' = \frac 32 x'$

Comment: Ultimately, the answer is that the image is a line-segment through the origin